# Calling [noun] using another word

Tags: grammar

How should I say when I want to call a noun with another word?

- Here we call [noun] a [noun].
- Here we call a [noun] a [noun].

edit from comments

> Here we call a tin "a can".

or

> Here we call "a tin" "can."

Comment: Could you give us the actual sentence?

Comment: - Here we call a tin "a can." or "Here we call "a tin" "can."

Answer (score 1):

Some examples:

> In the US **we call them** [potato *chips*](https://sparkpeo.hs.llnwd.net/e2/guid/Spicy-Sweet-Potato-Chips/3dc6158f-d6f2-42be-bc97-22b1945d6275.jpg) **not** potato *crisps*.
>
> In the US **we call** [*lorries*](https://fasttruckinsurance-6z1vhabg5fm8xjxr.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Lorry-Insurance.jpg) *trucks*.
>
> In the UK a [*sweater*](https://i.s-jcrew.com/is/image/jcrew/38102_GY6469?$pdp_enlarge$) **is called** a *jumper*.
>
> In the UK **you rent** a [*flat*](https://07f138315bb5e97f9e43-31068357019044cca7c8e84d92de0d99.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/640x480/56587_11491_001.jpg), **not** an *apartment*.
>
> In Australia a [*sidewalk*](http://www.coffsonline.com/images/P1000831.jpg) **is** a *footpath*.
>
> In the UK **they're** [*biscuits*](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-811146c12ec14458dd4df032d4569f81-c) **instead** of *cookies*.

And many others.  In general, you can use any of these with any noun, for example

> In the US we call *biscuits* *cookies*.  A [biscuit](http://www.cookingmaniac.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/buttermilk-biscuit-1.jpg) is something totally different.